# How do I disable the horizontal scrolling in my website? Or how can I set my header and content so it fits the width of the screen?

Tags: html, css, header, width

thanks for the help in advance. I recently started a website and have the problem that its header, content and footer are too wide, so they allow people to scroll to the right, even though that is completely unnecessary. I hid the horizontal scroll with overflow, but people can still scroll to the right with a mouse or their touch screens. If I make the width of said elements 100%, they do not fit the whole width of the screen, reason why I set them up to 105%. What can I do to fix this? This is the link to my website http://wwtcomics.com/.
And here is the css code:

```
.top {background-color: #FF0000;
height:12vw;
min-height:80px;
margin-top: -15px;
margin-left: -10px;
margin-right: -20px;
width:105%;}

.content{background-color:white;
margin: -25px -20px 0px -10px;
color: black;
font-family: Nunito;
width:105%;
position:relative;}

.footer{background-color: #FC6900;
margin-bottom: -15px;
margin-left: -10px;
margin-right: -20px;
width:105%;
height: 50px;
position:relative;}
```

Thank you for your help, I have been battling with this issue for some months now.

Comment: Please create a short, reproducible issue, and post all code for that here. You can read more on how to ask a good questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

**This is your current code which does not make sense:**
Why did you even make the width 105% ?

```
    .top {background-color: #FF0000;
    height:12vw;
    min-height:80px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -20px;
    width:105%;}

    .content{background-color:white;
    margin: -25px -20px 0px -10px;
    color: black;
    font-family: Nunito;
    width:105%;
    position:relative;}

    .footer{background-color: #FC6900;
    margin-bottom: -15px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -20px;
    width:105%;
    height: 50px;
    position:relative;}
```

**Correct Code:**

```
    .top {background-color: #FF0000;
    height:12vw;
    min-height:80px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -20px;
    width:100%;}

    .content{background-color:white;
    margin: -25px -20px 0px -10px;
    color: black;
    font-family: Nunito;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;}

    .footer{background-color: #FC6900;
    margin-bottom: -15px;
    margin-left: -10px;
    margin-right: -20px;
    width:100%;
    height: 50px;
    position:relative;}
```

Comment: I did have it as 100% at first, but for some reason it does not cover the whole width, it leaves a gap between the header and the right scroll bar.

Comment: make it 100% and adjust the margin.

Answer (score 0):

After reviewing your site and your CSS...

Change all your widths for blocks such as `navigation`, `content` and `footer` to a width of `100%` and **NOT** `105%`

I just did this using the Google Chrome developer inspector and this resolves your issue.

Setting it to a width larger than `100%` will cause the scroll bar at the bottom.

Comment: If my answer has helped you, please tick that check mark ;) @Tonywwt

Comment: Also, just for appearance, go ahead and add `padding-right: 40px;` to the `.navigation` class in your CSS. That way your navigation isn't hugging the edge of the page. It also looks cleaner that way too :) @Tonywwt

Comment: Thanks! I tried to hit the the tick, but it says I don't have enough reputation to hit it, either way, thanks a lot for the help! Will look into the navigation padding right away!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help!

I have found a solution in another question. It was true that I have to change the `width` to 100%, but that makes a small white `margin` surrounding the webpage.

This code solved the whole problem:

```
html, body {
margin: 0;
}
```